# Doctrine2 ORM - persist operations taking a long time

Tags: performance, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 application that uses Doctrine2 ORM.

I am trying to create entities from an XML file, and then persist the entities. A typical XML file might contain a few thousand records that need to be persisted. Each record in the XML does not map directly onto a single entity, but onto an entity and then some other entities that are on the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship.

I can create the entity from the XML elements, but it comes to running "persist" on the entity, each operation takes around 2 seconds on my machine. With several thousand records being imported from the XML file, this is too slow for our needs.

Could anyone offer any help?

Comment: The way it was working was to create all the entities to be persisted and store in an array. Once the XML file had been read, it looped through the array and ran "persist" on each entity. Then it called "flush". I realise now that this is not the best way. It should persist each entity as it is created, and then flush after periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Batch Processing in Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html). The idea is to call `persist()` on each new entity but use `flush()` only after a group of `n` entities are persisted. It will take less time than calling `persist()` then `flush()` for every entity.

For example:

```
$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
    $user = new CmsUser;
    $user->setStatus('user');
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i);
    $user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);
    $em->persist($user);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
    }
}
$em->flush();
```

I removed `clear()` since it will detach all the entities. It's a problem if for example you used a `foreach() {}` with entities, since Doctrine2 would detach the entities, the loop would be *broken*.

Without using `clear()`, Doctrine2 keep in memory all the persisted entities, it can cause an error if it takes more memory than PHP can use.

If you are iterating the loop on something else than Doctrine repositories, then you can call `clear()` after `flush()`.

Comment: This is nice example even today. Don't forgot to add $em->flush() after loop. If loop has 10016 items, last 16 items has not been persisted in this way.

Comment: @levye Thanks for the hint. Yes, this is not necessary here since we create a known number of items. But if you populate data from another source and number of items is unknown then don't forget to add the flush after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

Here is how I got it working quicker;

After 20 of my entities were created and persisted, I called flush() and clear() on the entity manager. This then meant that a related entity that needed to be linked to the entities I was creating was lost to doctrine, so it needed to be reloaded from the database.

It now takes around 0.02 seconds per entity - which is not exactly lightening fast, but is much quicker